# Data Entry gives 42000 sqlstate after SQL Server database migration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Brief synopsis: a SQL Server database was migrated from SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012 R2 STD to SQL Server 2017 on Windows Server 2016 STD. Still running in 110 compatibility mode and no SQL Server changes.

The application was repointed and using ODBC to connect. The following error is seen whenever a user attempts data entry/changes via the application. I have attached the stored procedure code which caused the error. The table definition in SSMS shows an `id` column `NOT NULL` so nothing wrong with the DDL. I have run `sp_blitz` and it highlighted 'Objects created with dangerous SET Options' for the offending database. The sp_blitz URL takes me to https://www.brentozar.com/go/badset which highlights incorrect settings for QUOTED IDENTIFIERS. This might be a red herring but I am at a loss as to the underlying problem and would welcome some input.

Errors:

Ah it seems I'm not permitted to insert images so its a little difficult to share the problem. The error message says

> Executing <sp_name> procedure SQLSTATS=42000 Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 Must declare the scalar variable

The stored procedure script with name masked:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[xxxxxxxx] 
    @sTable varchar(40), 
    @lnew_id integer OUTPUT
AS  
BEGIN   
    SET @lnew_id = -1;      
    SET @sTable = UPPER(@sTable);   

    SELECT @lnew_id = id_lastused 
    FROM idnext WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) 
    WHERE id_table = @sTable;   

    IF @@error = 0      
    BEGIN
        IF (@lnew_id IS NULL)       
        BEGIN
            SET @lnew_id = -1;          
        END

        IF (@lnew_id >= 0)      
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION tu    

            SET @lnew_id = @lnew_id + 1

            UPDATE idnext 
            SET id_lastused = @lnew_id 
            WHERE id_table = @sTable;

            IF (@@error = 0)                
            BEGIN
                COMMIT TRANSACTION tu;      
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION tu;
                SET @lnew_id = -999;
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @lnew_id = 1;       

            BEGIN TRANSACTION ti            
                INSERT INTO idnext (id_table, id_lastused) 
                VALUES (@sTable, @lnew_id);                 

                IF (@@error = 0)
                BEGIN
                    COMMIT TRANSACTION ti;      
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ti;    
                    SET @lnew_id = -998;
                END
            END 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @lnew_id = -997;
    END 
    RETURN (@lnew_id); 
END
```

Comment: *What* scalar variable? The message should include the name.

Comment: Also, can you replicate the error when executing the procedure manually (through Management Studio), or does it only happen from the application? If there are multiple or cascading errors client libraries can occasionally obscure the real cause.

Comment: Nothing about the posted code appears to be syntactically incorrect. But why is it trying to reinvent `SEQUENCE`? And why is it assuming table names will only be code page character names up to 40 characters long? (Object names including tables, views and columns are `SYSNAME` which is a synonym for `NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL`.)

Comment: Could there be one or more triggers on `idnext`?

Comment: Hi. I have requested more detail from the code application provider in order to replicate the error but noting forthcoming yet. The application has been running without problems on the old server for some time (years) but the issue only manifests in the new environment. There is more detail on the error:

Comment: 515 SQLSTAE 23000 Cannot insert the value NULLinto column xxx_id  table xxxxx.dbo.xxxx column does not allow nulls.

Comment: I'm not questioning the code as it was working before.

Comment: The code I posted is I think just an example as the NULL error seems to be appearing across any part of the application that is creating new data so its affecting many tables.

Comment: You've posted two very different errors. Which one is the issue?

Comment: OK ignore the 42000 as it refers to syntax error. I was given this initially but without anything else its pretty useless. The NULL error is I believe the important one that repeats, followed by the 42000. Without the ability to reproduce I cant help you/me with anything else.

Comment: Did you also copy all data over? The proc you have here is an overcomplicated and error prone. It was probably the only option back when it was written but not any more. At a guess. some piece of key data is missing , meaning that your proc returns a NULL and something tries to insert that NULL into a non nullable field. There is a lot more investigation that needs to be done but it doesn't sound like you can make any progress there

Comment: _the NULL error seems to be appearing across any part of the application that is creating new data_ it looks like this proc you have posted is the central "Key generation" proc that is used to find the next id for every table. So if this proc is (incorrectly) returning NULL then no tables will work. I know that code has worked forever, but something in your migration broke it

Comment: _Without the ability to reproduce I cant help you_ Have you tried just calling the proc directly in SSMS to see what happens?

Comment: Hi Nick you are right. I cant get much if any help from the supplier. Remember the code still works on the old server. All I did was backup the database and restore on the new server. No changes and still at 110 compatibility level. Other databases on the new server work with no issues after the same migration process. There is some vital piece of information that is missing.

Comment: So you have the db and app there to investigate and reproduce. Have you tried just calling the proc directly in SSMS to see what happens? There are a lot of moving parts to this. As already mentioned, a newer client library might change something subtly. If this is a piece of vendor code they really need to update it to use sequence. The code you have posted is out of date and liable to cause these types of mystery issues

Comment: I just tried calling the proc with no parameters and that gives a NULL error obviously. It works if I give it either a value (1) or leave it as NULL for the Id, but fails without the table value.